# Error Installing Custom DNN Module

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I have created a custom DNN module, but it fails when I install:

*A critical error has occurred. Could not find file 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Customers\RevIndex\RevIndexDNN.Web\Install\Temp\hlivdv1q\Test.dnn'.*

Here are the steps I took:

1. I created a module with this manifest called test.dnn:

http://pastebin.com/qKVqNYEg

I zipped up the project and it looks like this:

[image]

I placed the zip folder in the Install/Modules folder. I went to host > extensions and I clicked manage. I selected the Install/Modules/MyModule.zip folder and I received this error:

A critical error has occurred. Could not find file 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Customers\RevIndex\RevIndexDNN.Web\Install\Temp\hlivdv1q\Test.dnn'.

Why can't it find my manifest?

My site is running as local system and I uploaded it from my desktop.

Comment: I would start by uploading it to the HOST/EXTENSIONS page manually, see if you get any other information during the installation that way.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean uploading it from the desktop? Please give me more info on uploading it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the Host/Extensions page, choose the Install Extension Wizard and upload the ZIP file for your module (from whatever location you have it at)

From there you should see if there are any errors and hopefully get a more detailed log of the problem.

Comment: What ended up being the issue?

Comment: I am unsure. I found a workaround. I went to Host > Extensions > Manage and I used the create new module wizard.

Comment: Cool, I'm hoping to do a new release of the templates next week

Answer (score 1):

Often times this is a bit misleading.  I would start by checking to ensure that the ASP.NET worker process is able to write to the root of the site and all child folders.

The reason for this assumption is that since it knows it is looking for Test.dnn it was able to read the zip, just couldn't read the physical file that should have been put on disk.

Comment: Thanks. My software runs as local system, yet I still get this error.